# Pyodbc and Access with query parameter that contains a period

Tags: sql, python-3.x, ms-access, pyodbc

I recently found a bug with some Access SQL queries that I can't seem to track down.  I have a fairly straightforward SQL query that I use to retrieve data from an access database that's "managed" in an older application (ie the data is already in the database and I have no real control over what's in there).

```
import pyodbc
MDB = '******.MDB'
DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}'
PWD = ''

con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={};DBQ={};PWD={}'.format(DRV, MDB, PWD))
sql = ('SELECT Estim.PartNo, Estim.Descrip, Estim.CustCode, Estim.User_Text1, Estim.Revision, ' +
       'Estim.Comments, Routing.PartNo AS RPartNo, Routing.StepNo, Routing.WorkCntr, Routing.VendCode, ' +
       'Routing.Descrip AS StepDescrip, Routing.SetupTime, Routing.CycleTime, ' +
       'Routing.WorkOrVend, ' +
       'Materials.PartNo as MatPartNo, Materials.SubPartNo, Materials.Qty, ' +
       'Materials.Unit, Materials.TotalQty, Materials.ItemNo, Materials.Vendor ' +
       'FROM (( Estim ' +
       'INNER JOIN Routing ON Estim.PartNo = Routing.PartNo ) ' +
       'INNER JOIN Materials ON Estim.PartNo = Materials.PartNo )')

if 'PartNo' in kwargs:
    key = kwargs['PartNo']
    sql = sql + 'WHERE Estim.PartNo=?'
    cursor = con.cursor().execute(sql, key)

    # use this for debuging only
    num = 0
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        num += 1
    return num
```

This works fine for all `PartNo` except when `PartNo` contains a decimal point. Curiously, when `PartNo` contains a decimal point AND a hyphen, I get the appropriate record(s).

```
kwargs['PartNo'] = "100.100-2" # returns 1 record
kwargs['PartNo'] = "200.100" # returns 0 records
```

Both `PartNo`s exist when viewed in the other application, so I know there should be records returned for both queries.

My first thought was to ensure `kwargs['PartNo']` is a string `key = str(kwargs['PartNo'])` with no change.

I also tried to places quotes around the `'PartNo'` value with no success. `key = '\'' + kwargs['PartNo'] + '\''`

Finally, I tried to escape the `.` with no success (I realize this would break most queries, but I'm just trying to track down the issue with a single period) `key = str(kwargs['partNo']).replace('.', '"."')`

I know using query parameters should handle all the escaping for me, but at this point, I'm just trying to figure out what's going on.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What do you see if you `print(repr(key))` immediately after `key = kwargs['PartNo']` ...?

Comment: So in that case your upstream process is passing the argument as a number, not a string, and when `str(...)` converts it to string you get '200.1', not '200.100'. You need to fix your upstream process to consistently pass a string, even when it "looks like" a number.

Comment: I thought keyword arguments were inherently strings?  Interestingly, when I run this from the cmd line, I get the truncated strings.  When I run this through the flask framework that this function is a part of and `return repr(key)` I get `200.100` in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

So the issue isn't with the query parameters - everything works as it should.  The problem is with the SQL statement.  I incorrectly assumed - and never checked - that there was a record in the `Materials` table that matched `PartNo`.

```
INNER JOIN Materials ON Estim.PartNo = Materials.PartNo
```

will only return a record if `PartNo` is found in both tables, which in this particular case it is not.

Changing it to

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN Materials ON Estim.PartNo = Materials.PartNo
```

produces the expected results.  See this for info on JOINS. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243855(v=office.12).aspx

As for `print (repr(key))` - flask handles the kwarg type upstream properly

```
 api.add_resource(PartAPI, '/api/v1.0/part/<string:PartNo>'
```

so when I ran this in the browser, I got the "full length" strings.  When run in the cmd line using `python -c .......` I was not handling the argument type properly as Gord pointed out, so it was truncating the trailing zeros.  I didn't think the flask portion was relevant, so I never added that in the original question.